# Clear specified range of contents and shapes

Tags: excel, vba

I need to remove all the content from a specific cell range (Y1:CZ100) in a worksheet (Drawing) and reset all cell's borders linestyles, fill color etc to none.  The range can have different content but will always be populated with various group objects and autoshapes as well as text, merged cells and cell borders/fill colour etc.  I've written the following macro to do this:

```
Option Explicit


Sub Remove_DOD()  'Remove Drive on Dock drawing, Product Count Table, reset formulae

Dim sh As Shape
Dim DrawRange As Range

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Remove DOD Drawing and Product Count table)
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
With Worksheets("Drawing")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set DrawRange = Range("Y1:CZ100")

    With DrawRange
        .UnMerge
        .Interior.Color = xlNone
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
        .ClearContents
    End With

    For Each sh In .Shapes
        If Not Application.Intersect(sh.TopLeftCell, DrawRange) Is Nothing Then
            If sh.Type = msoGroup Or sh.Type = msoAutoShape Then sh.Delete
        End If
    Next sh

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End With

End Sub
```

It works most of the time but will sometimes fail with `Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error` at the statement `If Not Application.Intersect(sh.TopLeftCell, DrawRange) Is Nothing Then` and I cannot figure out what causes it to happen.  When the error does occur, the With loop to clearcontent, unmerge etc always completes but some group items are still present in the range and other times they are all cleared.

Any insights as to a solution would be most welcome.

Update:

I tried changing the method for selecting the shapes to be deleted and stopped testing for the type of shape (since all in the range need to be deleted).  This is the code but it still sometimes fails with same `Run-time error 1004` at `s = .TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & .BottomRightCell.Address`.  The error seems to occur only after the contents of the Drawing range have been replaced with new shapes and the macro is run again. Sometimes it errors immediately and none of the new shapes are deleted but it can also be when and it has reached the end of deleting all these new shapes (i.e. on the last iteration of `With sh`). I think the error is because the value of `sh` is invalid but don't see why this happens. Perhaps I need to insert some way of testing the value of `sh`? Also, I have seen old posts on other forums with similar issues but solutions never provided.

```
Option Explicit


Sub Remove_DOD()  'Remove Drive on Dock drawing, Product Count Table, reset formulae

Dim sh As Shape
Dim S As String
Dim DrawRange As Range

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Remove DOD Drawing and Product Count table)
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
With Worksheets("Drawing")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set DrawRange = Range("Y1:CZ100")

    With DrawRange
        .UnMerge
        .Interior.Color = xlNone
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
        .ClearContents
    End With

    For Each sh In .Shapes
        With sh
            s = .TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & .BottomRightCell.Address
        End With
        If Not Intersect(DrawRange, .Range(s)) Is Nothing Then
            sh.Delete
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End With

End Sub
```

This fails the same way at `Set shRange = Range(sh.TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & sh.BottomRightCell.Address)` statement:

```
Option Explicit


Sub Remove_DOD()  'Remove Drive on Dock drawing, Product Count Table, reset formulae

Dim sh As Shape
Dim s As String
Dim DrawRange, shRange As Range

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Remove DOD Drawing and Product Count table)
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
With Worksheets("Drawing")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set DrawRange = Range("Y1:CZ100")

    With DrawRange
        .UnMerge
        .Interior.Color = xlNone
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
        .ClearContents
    End With

    For Each sh In .Shapes
        Set shRange = Range(sh.TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & sh.BottomRightCell.Address)
        If Not Intersect(shRange, DrawRange) Is Nothing Then sh.Delete
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End With

End Sub
```

Not very satisfactory but the following now works. Note the inclusion of `On Error Resume Next` in the `For Each sp`loop.  This forces the loop to exit when the error is encountered.

```
Option Explicit


Sub Remove_DODTest()  'Remove Drive on Dock drawing, Product Count Table, reset formulae

Dim sh As Shape
Dim DrawRange As Range

With Worksheets("Drawing")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Remove DOD Drawing and Product Count table
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Set DrawRange = .Range("Y1:CZ100")

    With DrawRange
        .UnMerge
        .Interior.Color = xlNone
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
        .ClearContents
    End With

    For Each sh In .Shapes
        On Error Resume Next
        If Not Application.Intersect(sh.TopLeftCell, DrawRange) Is Nothing Then sh.Delete
    Next sh

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Important - you're missing a period: `Set DrawRange = .Range("Y1:CZ100")`.

Comment: Agreed but unfortunately it doesn't fix the problem.  The code fails within the `For Each sh In.Shapes` loop.  If I debug it I can see it goes through  the loop many times successfully deleting the various shape types it encounters but then often errors at the end.  Do not understand why.

Comment: One idea I had was to create a [`ShapeRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shaperange) of shapes to delete and then delete once at the end (haven't tried it yet though).

Comment: Thanks for your idea but have not had any success at coding this.  I tried another approach to the `sh loop` (see latest edit) but still get same failure.  Any tips you have for coding using `ShapeRange` would be appreciated.

Comment: Some more information from using Debug and the Locals Window.  When the loop errors, all shapes have been cleared but for some reason `sh` still has a `MsoAutoTypeShape` of `msoShapedMixed` but both `BottomRightCell` and `TopLeftCell` have values of `<Application-defined or object-defined error>` which obviously stops the code.  In other words the loop is entered because `sh` has a type associated with it but there's no defined `cell address` associated with it so the `Intersect` fails.  Can I somehow test for this condition and exit the loop if it occurs?

Comment: Have a fix.  Not that satisfactory but it works - see latest update